# Pivot table export excel for header group

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How to excel export for pivot table?

```
 Name  Code   shop  sum1 sum2
  A      1    16     2      3
  B      2    14     4      3
  C      4    13     2      5
  D      3    33     1      6
```

Name, code => rowGroup / shop => pivot

Then, it looks like on the screen.

```
 Name  Code   total1 total2   sum1 sum2  sum1 sum2
  A      1      6      6       2     3     4   3    ...
```

but I export excel. It looks like

[image]

I want to export excel like this picture. What should I change to look the same as this?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Youjin, I'm facing the same problem. Have you managed to find out a solution for this? I think that the groupHideOpenParents feature isn't applied to the exported file, but I don't understand why unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I was right in my comment on the question. This is because groupHideOpenParents is not applied to the exported file. This is a known issue. It is among the "Standard Feature Requests" in the ag-Grid Pipeline: https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/. Ticket key: AG-3756 [Excel Export] Allow groupHideOpenParents to apply in Excel export

Unfortunately it is in the backlog, so it can't be known when it will be fixed and released. Based on this blog entry: https://ag-grid.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002213531-Where-Is-My-Ticket-

"Standard Feature Requests are usually fixed within 2 to 4 releases after they have been raised."